# Why am I not getting all columns from this Union?

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to unify two distincts notebooks into a single one by adapting the logic of construction of two different tables.

The first one reads:

```
spark.sql(''' SELECT CD_CLI, 
                 MAX(VL_RPTD_UTZO) AS MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO,
                 '2017-01-31' AS DT_MVTC
          FROM vl_rptd_utzo
          WHERE DT_EXTC BETWEEN '2016-07-31' AND '2016-12-31'
          GROUP BY CD_CLI                                                                                           
      ''').createOrReplaceTempView('vl_rptd_max_utzo_2017_01_31')
```

And the second one:

```
spark.sql('''SELECT CD_CLI,
                CASE WHEN SUM(in_lim_crt) > 0 
                    THEN ROUND(SUM(SUM_VL_TTL_FAT)/SUM(in_lim_crt), 4)
                    ELSE -99999999999
                    END AS VL_MED_FAT,
                '2017-01-31' as DT_MVTC
         FROM in_lim_fat
         WHERE DT_MVTC BETWEEN '2016-07-31' AND '2016-12-31'
         GROUP BY CD_CLI
      ''').createOrReplaceTempView('media_vl_fatura_2017_01_31')
```

My, perhaps naive?, approach was to union the two selects since they are calling the same fields from the same origin:

```
spark.sql('''SELECT CD_CLI,
                CASE WHEN SUM(in_lim_crt) > 0 
                    THEN ROUND(SUM(SUM_VL_TTL_FAT)/SUM(in_lim_crt), 4)
                    ELSE -99999999999
                    END AS VL_MED_FAT,
                '2017-01-31' as DT_MVTC
         FROM in_lim_fat
         WHERE DT_MVTC BETWEEN '2016-07-31' AND '2016-12-31'
         GROUP BY CD_CLI
         UNION
         SELECT CD_CLI,
                 MAX(VL_RPTD_UTZO) AS MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO,
                 '2017-01-31' AS DT_MVTC
         FROM vl_rptd_utzo
         WHERE DT_EXTC BETWEEN '2016-07-31' AND '2016-12-31'
         GROUP BY CD_CLI
      ''').createOrReplaceTempView('new_table')
```

But when I ask for a describe:

```
spark.sql('describe new_table').show(10, False)
```

The output is:

```
+----------+-------------+-------+
|col_name  |data_type    |comment|
+----------+-------------+-------+
|CD_CLI    |int          |null   |
|VL_MED_FAT|decimal(38,4)|null   |
|DT_MVTC   |string       |null   |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

Why MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO is not showing up in the new table? I am new to sql and maybe this is very naive and simple but I cannot solve it.

Comment: You SELECT 3 columns, and get 3 columns. Just as expected. (The column names are taken from the first SELECT.)

Comment: Do `select c1, c2, c3, null` etc to get 4 columns. And perhaps you want UNION ALL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first select has `CD_CLI`, `VL_MED_FAT` and `DT_MVTC`

Your second select has `CD_CLI`, `MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO` and `DT_MVTC`

Spark will use the column name of the first query as the schema and apply it to other subsequence queries in the union, therefore values of `MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO` will appear in `VL_MED_FAT`.

Edit #1: If you want to have 4 columns then it has to be consistence between 2 queries, so something like this

```sql
select CD_CLI, VL_MED_FAT, null as MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO, DT_MVTC from ...
union
select CD_CLI, null as VL_MED_FAT, MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO, DT_MVTC from ...
```

Comment: I see. Can I have values of MAX_VL_RPTD_UTZO not in VL_MED_FAT but appearing independently? I mean, can I have 4 columns by using another query method othar than UNION?

Comment: Yes of course, check my updated answer

Comment: ok!!! thanks! I didn't know I could these "null AS..." to construct the table. So it was very simple as I thought. Thanks a lot.

Comment: well you used `'2017-01-31' as DT_MVTC` to construct the table, so it's essentially the same :)